# What is the proper way to check kafka cluster health?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-elb

I'm developing an application that uses Kafka cluster behind an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS and I'm wondering, what is the best way to check health of instances in kafka cluster ?

Did anyone had a similar issue ?

Comment: You can monitor the health of the instance from Server Monitoring provided by AWS or integrate third party service for example Datadog or some thing else.

Comment: I was looking for something that i can use as ELB health check. For more complex monitoring I plan on using kafkabeats.

Comment: AWS Console provides ELB Health check too?

Comment: I mean, to ELB to work properly, you need to provide some kind of health checking mechanism based on which ELB can decide if machine in ASG is alive.

Answer (score 1):

We typically use a TCP call on either port 9092 or 9093, depending on whether your Kafka brokers are secure or not. I think you can potentially customise the port they listen on too, but those are the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Have been over this subject for a while and following is one the best one we managed to come up with. We are using kubernetes, so the configuration will be bit different to your environment, but you could adjust accordingly:

```
startupProbe:
exec:
  command:
    - sh
    - '-c'
    - >
      [[ "$(kafka-broker-api-versions --bootstrap-server
      localhost:9092 | grep 9092 | wc -l)" == "3" ]] || { echo >&2
      "Broker count is not 3"; exit 1; } && [[ "$(curl -s
      kafka-controller-headless.my-namespace:9102/metrics
      | grep
      kafka_controller_kafkacontroller_preferredreplicaimbalancecount
      | tail -n 1 | grep -o '[^ ]\+$')" == "0.0" ]] || { echo >&2
      "Replica Imbalance not 0"; exit 1; }
```

Here the "kafka-controller-headless.my-namespace" is the kubernetes service name of the "controller" (KRAFT)

What this does is that:

- It will first check whether the broker count is matching (which is 3 for our setup)
- It then also check for the "replica imbalance" to be zero - this prevents the brokers to not go down till the cluster is in balance